# How to identify a mounted device as removable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I figure out if a mounted device can be unmounted/ejected ?

I tried to get all devices with the help of the `NSFileManager`.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeURLForRemountingKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, nil];
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:0];

for (NSURL *url in urls) 
{
NSError *error;
NSNumber *isRemovable;
NSString *volumeName; 

[url getResourceValue:&isRemovable forKey:NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey error:&error];
[url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];

NSLog(@"Standard Device : %@ - Removable: %c", volumeName, [isRemovable boolValue]);

}
```

But when I iterate through the list, I always get this e.g.:

```
Standard Device Name: My Book - isEjectable:
```

FYI, "My Book" is a USB drive.

I hope someone can point out what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Your log line should probably look like this: NSLog(@"Standard Device : %@ - Removable: %@", volumeName, [isRemovable boolValue] ? @"yes" : @"no"); But I get no removable or ejectable drive in this list.

Comment: Well, that makes the logging clearer but the result is the same, my USB drive is not identified as removable device.

Comment: There is a distinction between "removable device" and "removable media". USB makes the concepts blur because you can plug in media such as a USB stick or an SSD with fixed media or a DVD drive with removable media.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey` not `NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey`.

`NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey` means the media can be physically removed from the device.  `NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey` indicates that the volume can be unmounted.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same, both 'NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey' and 'NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey' do not seem to be filled

Comment: Huh -- yeah -- I just ran similar code and also don't ever see YES for IsEjectable/IsRemovable.  How odd.   I don't have time to debug this right now, but will try to do so sometime soon (as my curiosity is now quite thoroughly piqued).

Comment: On my 2013 MacBook Air I haven't found any device yet where these two keys ever have different values.

Comment: @hippietrail Try mounting a piece of removable media and then CD'ing into a directory on that piece of media and opening a file.

That might trigger a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `NSURLVolumeIsInternalKey` to determine if a volume can be removed from a Mac.

When using this key, you can get the following results:

- 0      = Volume is external and can be removed
- 1      = Volume is internal and cannot be removed
- (null) = Volume is not connected to the Mac, such as a network share

[This link](https://github.com/boyvanamstel/VolumeEjectableBug) contains some clarification from an Apple engineer why the `NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey` and `NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey` keys cannot be used to determine the removability of a volume.